# Convert .txt to json using Shell scripting

Tags: json, shell, jq

I have a text file `data.txt`:

```
Framework1,Version1
Framework2,Version2
Framework3,Version3
```

I need to convert it to `data.json` which would look like:

```
[
{"FrameworkName":"Framework1", "VersionName":"Version1"},
{"FrameworkName":"Framework3", "VersionName":"Version2"},
{"FrameworkName":"Framework3", "VersionName":"Version3"}
]
```

I have tried using `awk` but it hasn't helped me much. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the data type in txt file? I mean input data type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**`jq`** solution:

```
jq -Rs '[ split("\n")[] | select(length > 0) 
          | split(",") | {FrameworkName: .[0], VersionName: .[1]} ]' data.txt
```

The output:

```
[
  {
    "FrameworkName": "Framework1",
    "VersionName": "Version1"
  },
  {
    "FrameworkName": "Framework2",
    "VersionName": "Version2"
  },
  {
    "FrameworkName": "Framework3",
    "VersionName": "Version3"
  }
]
```

https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/

Comment: Lovely... Also output all this to a json file  `[your above code]  > file.json` :)